# Servicestack : Specified method not supported

Tags: c#, linq, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am getting a method not specified error after adding **Any** in the query.
Please find the below snippet

**Models**

```
public class BodyTatoo
  {
    public BodyTatoo()
    {

    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<BodyTattooColor> TattooColors {get;set;} = new List<BodyTattooColor>();

}

  public class BodyTattooColor
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Color))]
    public int ColorId{ get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(BodyTatoo)]
    public Guid BodyTattooId { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public BodyTatoo BodyTatoo { get; set; }

  }

  public class Color
  { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
-------------------------------------------------
```

**Request DTO**

```
     public class RequestDto : IReturn<Result>
      { 
        // It can be comma separated value eg: "Black, Green, Red etc.."
        public string Colors { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
      }

   

 public List<Result> Get(RequestDto request)
    {
    
    var query = Db.From<>()
                  .leftJoin<BodyTatoo,BodyTattooColor>()
                  .leftJoin<BodyTattooColor,Color>();
    
    var colorArray = request.colors.split(",");
    
   query = query.Or<BodyTatoo>(x => x.BodyTattooColor
                .Any(v => colorArray.Any(c => v.Color.Name.Contains(c))));

    }
```

Let me know if there is any way to resolve that.

query = query.Or(x => x.BodyTattooColor
.Any(v => colorArray.Any(c => v.Color.Name.Contains(c))));
this line is giving the issue.

Comment: Please update your question to include the **actual** real source code of the Request DTO & Service class that's failing and the full Exception StackTrace. Non compilable pseudo code isn't useful when trying to identify issues.

Comment: It seems to be your "Any()" methods which are failing.

Answer (score -1):

ok, So I am able to fix the issue by using the below code.

```
query = query.Or<BodyTattooColor>(x => colorArray.Any(c => x.Color.Name.Contains(c))));
```